# What is the difference between Visual Studio normal mode and safe mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, vmware

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Resharper on a VMWare VM.  The VM and host OS have no performance problems.

However, when I try to work on a large C# project in Visual Studio, the application maxes out the VM's CPU - routinely around 90% usage, but never below 50%.  If you look at devenv.exe in Process Monitor, you can see that it's accessing thousands of files and registry keys every second, even when the application should be completely idle.

When I run VS in safe mode, the problem completely goes away.  After parsing/scanning #included files and running for a little while, VS' cpu usage drops to < 1%.

So here's my question: what does safe mode exclude?  I tried suspending Resharper, but it didn't seem to change anything.  Ideally, I would like to keep Resharper running, but disable any other extensions/services so that I have simply the core needed for VS.

In other words, here's my question: If running VS normally runs `E, I, R, x, y, z`, where E = basic VS environment, I = intellisense, R = resharper, x=y=z= miscellaneous, how do I manually select the features to run so that I get `E, I, R` (instead of just `E` which is what I get through safe mode)?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms241278(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: That's not helpful; I understand that it's only the default environment and services.  But my question is asking how I can revert to that state manually without going into safe mode, so that I can run Resharper.

Comment: I deleted my answer after you edit your question, thank you for completing question.
but I think reinstalling VS solve your problem yet :)